# Difference between tx and rx?

Tags: voip, asterisk

With asterisk I can set the volume of TX and RX. But what are those options? I've already googled this but can't find anything.

Whats is the difference between TX and RX?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

RX is receive, incoming.
TX is transmitting, outgoing.